# C# WPF Изменение формы (перемещение) по нажатию клавиши

Tags: c#, wpf, key, keydown

Изучаю WPF. Хочу поиграться с элементами управления, изменить форму по нажатию клавиши, а потом переместить. но столкнулся с банальной проблемой. Хочу изменить форму по нажатию клавиши, ошибок в коде нет, но код не работает

```
namespace tanks
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }


    private void MessageBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            InputBox.Text = $"Высота: {Tank.Height} \nШирина: {Tank.Width}";

        }

        private void Tank_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {

                Tank.Height = 1020;
            }
        }

        private void Map_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void InputBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

и xaml

```
<Window x:Class="tanks.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="Map" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="505" Margin="10,10,10,55" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="772" KeyDown="Map_KeyDown">
            <Rectangle Name="Tank" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="40" Canvas.Left="323" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="393" Width="30" KeyDown="Tank_KeyDown"/>
        </Canvas>
        <TextBox Name="InputBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="10,520,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" TextChanged="MessageBox_TextChanged" KeyDown="InputBox_KeyDown"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваш `Tank` может получать клавиатурный фокус? Почему вы отслеживаете нажатия на нем?

Comment: Не совсем понял что имеется в виду под "клавиатурным фокусом" . Если под отслеживанием имеется в виду, зачем я в textbox вывожу ширину и высоту, то на самом деле, я просто ради интереса добавил это свойство. Сюда я скопировал весь код, потому что вообще не понимаю в чем проблема. Может быть я не добавил какое-то свойств

Comment: @jimac Андрей имеет ввиду то, что у элемента есть два фокуса. Вот статья у майков: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/focus-overview

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что Rectangle скорее всего не перехватывает нажатия клавиш, потому что вы на него фокус даже не можете поставить. Поэтому нажатия надо ловить где-то в другом месте, например, на окне

Comment: Действительно так.. не могу понять, но и grid и canvas и фигура не могут обработать событие по нажатию клавиши. Когда вписал код нажатия клавиши,  в InputBox событие KeyDown, и в поле inputBox нажимаю клавиши WASD, то событие срабатывает и фигура перемещается.

Comment: пример кода:`private void InputBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            
            //InputBox.Text += e.Key.ToString();
            if (e.Key == Key.W)
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(Tank, Canvas.GetTop(Tank) - 5);
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Проблему частично решил. Нужно вставить элемент управления по типу кнопки и в ней вносить изменения. Судя по книжке Адама Натана "WPF4 подробное руководство", должен быть фокус клавиатуры на элементе, через свойство IsKeyboardFocused. Но я пока не понял как его реализовать в пустом месте формы